# jquery: How to add new line to text when comma occured

Tags: jquery, html

I have one text box which get multiple email id from user. And showing it in tooltip but i need to show each email (seperated by comma) on new line.
For that, need to detect comma & add new line character to it.

HTML is

```
  <input type="text" id="email"> <div id="ttip"></div>
```

jquery for tooltip

```
$("#email").keyup(showTooltip);

var showTooltip = function(e) {
    var tooltip = $(this).val();
    if (tooltip == '') {
        hideTooltip();
    } else if (e.which == 188) {
        tooltip += "<br>";
        $("#ttip").fadeIn().html(tooltip);
    } else {
        $("#ttip").fadeIn().html(tooltip);
    }
}​
```

So when my tooltip is displaying in div it didn't detect `<br>` and it is showing on same line.
How can I fix it?

Comment: Maybe it didn't work because you had <br> instead of <br/>?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
$("#email").keyup(showTooltip);

            var showTooltip=function(e){
            var tooltip=$(this).val();
                    if(tooltip ==''){
                            hideTooltip();
                    }else if(e.which == 188){
                           tooltip = tooltip.replace(/,/g,"<br />");
                            $("#ttip").fadeIn().html(tooltip);
                    }else{              
                            $("#ttip").fadeIn().html(tooltip);
                    }   
            }
```

Comment: I'd use `/,/g` instead so it replaces all instaces of the comma

Comment: you do know replace returns a string. It doesn't actually mutate the old string.

Comment: "It is not working" is not working for us.  It tells us nothing.  How doesn't it work?  what's the value of tooltip after the replacement?  What's the value of #ttip's html if you use `alert($("#ttip").html());`.  Help us out!

Comment: It is showing value first time when comma entered **user1@mail.com**
second time **user1@mail.com,user2@mail.com**

Answer (score 1):

You are undoing the previous change each time.
Don't check if a comma has been typed before replacing the value.

```
var showTooltip = function(e) {
    var tooltip = $(this).val();
    if (tooltip == '') {
        hideTooltip();
    } else {
        tooltip = tooltip.replace(/,/g, '<br />');
        $("#ttip").fadeIn().html(tooltip);
    }
}
$("#email").keyup(showTooltip);​
```

View here: http://jsfiddle.net/lnrb0b/NK65G/
(I've commented out the `hideTooltip()` since I don't have the function)

Answer (score 1):

So this works: http://jsfiddle.net/ZgmFw/4/

```
var showTooltip = function(e) {
    var tooltip = $(this).val();
    if (tooltip == '') {
        hideTooltip();
    } else {
        $("#ttip").html(tooltip.replace(/,/g, "<br />")).fadeIn();
    }
}


$("#email").keyup(showTooltip);​
```